# Iterate over class properties and populate a Dictionary with the name and value

Tags: c#

```
public class rates
{
public double USD { get; set; }
public double ZAR { get; set; }
public double EUR { get; set; }

}
```

Is it possible to create a dictionary from the above object?

```
Dictionary<string, double> CurrencyRates;
```

The above properties in the rates class are being initialized from a Json file.

Comment: Deserialise the JSON directly into the dictionary.

Comment: or `var result = rates.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(rates));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. However, here is a direct *reflection* approach

**Given**

```
var rates = new rates(){EUR = 123,USD = 356,ZAR = 456};
```

**Usage**

```
var result = rates
   .GetType()
   .GetProperties()
   .ToDictionary(
      x => x.Name,
      x => (double)x.GetValue(rates));

foreach (var item in result)
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Value}");
```

**Output**

```
USD 356
ZAR 456
EUR 123
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing .ToDictionary() and trying to add it manually. Much apparentiated